# Html validation issue (tag problems)

Tags: html, validation

I'm having a problem with HTML validation.

I get 4 errors below:

http://pokit.org/get/?c6b1a535084f58d1147ada962484c4fa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) you are required to insert a `<legend>` tag as first element of a `<fieldset>`.

```
<form action="blank" id="formCreate">
    <fieldset id="fieldSetCreate">
      <legend>Input form</legend>
      <label for="nameCreate">Naziv </label>
      <input type="text" name="nameCreate" id="nameCreate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="descriptionCreate">Opis</label>
      <input type="text" name="descriptionCreate" id="descriptionCreate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="priceCreate">Cijena</label>
      <input type="text" name="priceCreate" id="priceCreate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <input type="submit" tabindex="1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Additionally the second form should also have a `<legend>` tag:

```
<form action="blank" id="formEdit">
    <fieldset id="fieldSetEdit">
      <legend>Input form</legend>
      <label for="nameEdit">Naziv </label>
      <input type="text" name="nameEdit" id="nameEdit"class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="descriptionEdit">Opis</label>
      <input type="text" name="descriptionEdit" id="descriptionEdit" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="priceEdit">Cijena</label>
      <input type="text" name="priceEdit" id="priceEdit" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <input type="submit" tabindex="1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```